# How to typeset a book where the odd pages are left blank?

Tags: blank-page

My request is as follows:

I have 93 pages of my book. I want to have my text on even pages and blank pages on odd ones. I want to have something like this:

```
page 1: my text
page 2: blank
page 3: my text
page 4: blank
page 5: my text
page 6: blank
page 7: my text
page 8: blank
[...]
page n: my text
page n+1: blank
```

My intended structure is like a one-sided book, where one reads the right side only.

Probably some command exists to leave odd pages empty, but I didn't find anything to do it automatically.

Comment: Welcome. Interesting question! But in the pdf do you want a blank page with even page number or do you want a pdf with only odd numbers as page numbers? For example, how many pages should have a pdf with (in theory) 4 pages?  Only 2, numbered as 1,3 or 4 pages, where pages 2,4 completely white?

Comment: Hi, i want to have either blank page and text pages with page numbers. For 2 my text pages i want to have 4 pdf pages. [text 1; blank 2; text 3;blank 4].